# How to select an option from a dynamic dropdown using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autosuggest, staleelementreferenceexception

I am trying to click on dropdown value to select city in from field in Make my trip http://www.makemytrip.com/. But getting Stale element reference exception. Ids are getting changed on page load. 
Tried below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hp-widget__sfrom']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-id-1']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hp-widget__sfrom']")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='ui-menu-item'][2]"))));
```

Comment: plz provide total exception faced to explain better why it is happen.

Comment: Thanks @muraliselenium for your response, but it is resolved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on a dropdown value e.g. **Mumbai** you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/")
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='input_fromto checkSpecialCharacters ui-autocomplete-input' and @id='hp-widget__sfrom']"))).click();
  List<WebElement> myList = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item'][starts-with(@id,'ui-id-')]//span[@class='autoCompleteItem__label']")));
  for (WebElement element:myList)
      if(element.getText().contains("Mumbai"));
          element.click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: from_mumbai]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just wanted to understand, why do I need to give class name in xpath in 'From' when id of From is unique.

Comment: @user2377826 So basically your question is why we have used an _xpath_ when an _id_ is present. In short using _class name_, _id_, _name_ or _tag name_ is converted into _css selector_ by the _Java Client_ by default. So the choice is between using _css selector_ or _xpath_. As your code trials were based on _xpath_, hence I did so. You can find a detailed discussion in [Official locator strategies for the webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this working code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hp-widget__sfrom']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hp-widget__sfrom']")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class='ui-menu-item'][2]/div/p[1]/span[1]"))).click();
```

I have fixed the xPath of dropdown list element. Always try to specify the exact element yo want to interact with. For example if you want to click on button, try to find `<span>` or `<button>` tag, for a link `<a>` tag and for input fields `<input>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

I do not see any use of **xpath** in this scenario. I have converted some of the **xpath** to either **css selector or id.** and have kept only one. Though I have not faced any stale element reference.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver  = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
        WebElement from =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("hp-widget__sfrom")));
        from.click();
        from.clear();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("ul[class*='ui-widget-content hp-widget__sfrom']")));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[contains(@aria-label,'Top Cities : Mumbai, India ')]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works fine for me and it is parameterized as well, it works for any input value without changing the xpath. In this example, I took mumbai as test data.

```
    driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'hp-widget__sfrom')]")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'hp-widget__sfrom')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'hp-widget__sfrom')]")).sendKeys("Mumbai");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    By option = By.xpath("//div[@class='autoCompleteItem']/p/span[contains(text(),'Mumbai')]");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(option));
    driver.findElement(option).click();
```